# Matlab: How to find all possible combinations from 2 vectors?

Tags: matlab, combinations

`V1` and `V2` are vectors `1x20` and `1x10` respectively.

How to find all possible combinations of 15 elements from `V1` and 3 elements from `V2`?

The order of the selected elements is not important.

Comment: that result set will be huge (millions of combinations): you take `nchoosek(20,15)` and `nchoosek(10,3)` then take all possible combinations from the two sets.. Do you need all of it?

Comment: @Amro: yes, I think 1860480 of combinations!

Comment: @Amro: I know that the result is to take all possible combinations from the two sets,  but I do not know how to translate it into matlab code without using for-loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
% n-choose-k from each vector
A = nchoosek(1:20,15);
B = nchoosek(1:10,3);

% all combinations from the two sets
[X,Y] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1), 1:size(B,1));
C = [A(X(:),:) B(Y(:),:)];
```

The result contains the indices from the two vectors V1 and V2:

```
>> whos C
  Name            Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes

  C         1860480x18            267909120  double
```

---

If you want to directly apply it to the actual vectors, replace the first two lines with:

```
A = nchoosek(V1,15);    % V1 is a 1x20 vector
B = nchoosek(V2,3);     % V2 is a 1x10 vector
```